# Python: Memory efficient sort of a list of tuples by two elements

Tags: python, sorting, memory

I have a very large list of tuples that I would like to sort by two elements. For example:

```
List = [('chr1', 34234, 'extrainfo'), ('chr1', 1234, 'extrainfo'), ('chr3', 4234, 'extrainfo'), ('chr1', 3241, 'extrainfo')]
```

This is a really large list and I wanted to sort using:

```
List = sorted(List, key=lambda i: (i[0], int[1])))
```

This works well when using smaller lists such as the above example. However, when I run my code using my much larger datasets I get memory errors:

```
Python(32306) malloc: *** mmap(size=34684928) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyCode.py", line 139, in <module>
    List = sorted(List, key=lambda i: (i[0], int(i[1])))
MemoryError
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort huge files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665925/how-to-sort-huge-files-with-python)

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error message.  It should probably say `int(i[1])` instead of `int[1]`.

Comment: Have you tried with `List.sort(...)`?

Comment: @dg99: Sorry about that - I copied it wrong...

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: I tried the list sort and got a similar error

Comment: Process the data in stages. It is the best way. That is what I personally do in my Ph.D. research in Computational Linguistics.

Comment: You can always edit your post to fix any copy/paste errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things you can try, roughly in order of difficulty/desirability.

- Don't create a sorted *copy* of the list using `sorted()`. Instead, sort the list in place using `List.sort()`.
- Sort the list twice, first with `key=lambda i: i[1]` and then with `key=lambda i: i[0]`. This will take longer, but the list of keys will require less space on each pass. Python`s sort is guaranteed stable in v2.2 and later. Sorting on the keys in the reversed order of their importance is the way we used to do it back when we could only sort on one key at a time.
- Don't use a key function at all. Sorting by the items in a tuple in order is the default behavior! You don't care about the order of the third and subsequent items, so why not just let Python go ahead and sort on them? They'll be in order too, but that's as good as any order. (This won't work if the other elements are types that don't support comparison.)
- Use a `cmp` function rather than a `key` function if your version of Python is old enough to support it. This will avoid generating a list of keys, but will be slower and won't work in Python 3.
- Use a 64-bit version of Python on a 64-bit OS on a machine with plenty of memory.
- Implement your own sort.

Comment: Also sort the list in-place using `List.sort()`, don't create a new list.

Comment: Oh, good point, I didn't even register that he was using `sorted()`.

Comment: Point 2. is wrong. Calling `int()` on an int object only increments the object ref count, it doesn't create a new object.

Comment: Whoops. Removed that. Thanks.

Comment: @kindall: The one method that worked was to do a straightforward List.sort(). Unfortunately while this appears to work in the smaller test dataset, in my larger set the numbers do not get sorted properly. For instance I will get 120009 before 13008.

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with strings, are you sure they're integers in your actual data?

Comment: @kindall: You're right. I just assumed the numbers would convert to integers, not strings. I changed that in the function reading in the data and now it sorts as it should...

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck using structured arrays for this as they are faster than lists for large data sets

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1. Increase the size of RAM.
2. Try to process little data at a time, especially if you are doing operations on corpora or texts, as it appears to be.

You seem to have similar keys. So try to use the feature counter which is imported from collections. If extra info is different, then you can use nesting.

This will save you a lot of trouble.