# How can I sort a dictionary by value without creating even a temporary copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, memory, memory-management

I have a dictionary, which I need to sort by key. I physically do not have enough memory to do it.

```python
x = dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
```

Is there a way to sort it without creating even a temporary spike in memory usage. I though I could maybe use `pop()`, to remove items from the original, to keep the same amount of data in memory? But I don't know if there is a simpler way to do it.

My dictionary is about 10^8 objects, which is taking up about 100 Gb. I have about 20-25 Gb of memory free.

Comment: How many items are in your dict?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before. you can check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23398170/10395731

Comment: The dictionary itself has a rather small memory footprint. The items it contains will not be copied but referenced.

Comment: @KlausD. How do you know that? Did they answer my question and deleted it already and I missed it?

Comment: Also, how much memory is still free?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I was asleep. My dictionary is about 10^8 objects, which is taking up about 100 Gb. I have about 20-25 Gb of memory free.

Comment: Then probably the dict itself is only ~5 GB large. And the key and value objects take ~95 GB, and those won't be duplicated. Did you actually try your approach and it failed? I estimate it takes only ~14 GB to work. And my answer's best approach should definitely work.

Comment: I can access my hardware in a few hours, and then it'll take about  a day to run, so I'll update this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *no* extra space, but much less, so maybe still useful for you or others with the same problem. Memory measurements (peak bytes) with 10^5 items:

```
12,059,636 baseline
24,408,256 original
19,065,304 better 1
18,709,352 better 2
14,265,296 sort keys, sort vals
12,949,792 sort keys, sort vals 2
```

`baseline` is for creating the original dict. Your `original` solution peaks at additional 12.3 MB. My best alternative peaks at additional 0.9 MB.

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPRauMwEHz3V@w9WSomND0OjoD/4t5KCbK9dkVkS0hq67Tk23MryY7rNld6L/HuZDQzu0Lm6B/18PO3seez7I22HrwVNfZCKV2DcOD7rLW6ByuGhj4TKXXZ1HV1lg1Qwvb25uZXljXYgvPCeqZEhYrvMoBO6UooGAuI2J6gVNCxWAROvam1Ulh7xqn1/SaphGYk3ltyZXwHcwWttrAHOQSkQzbw0@yvDVs5U2msHDxr8zeS7tDv46jNvsde2yPj99uH3fa2OOVzyEuKoEW1bOfQP0rIK@FQyQHz4AK0K4e0C4UDGzmUJQwrWDrPxs2zUE/oGI8ER7vD5j1afOKRRoMp/Wo92YfB72hW4qSFLdF4xGL85V9tZScHofJ5sY0kzUsa6bEn6wIOeCyV6KtGQMB28ZeWxK@qVug9WtheVKdRJrmIboIJ@6fu@zjjVyZ30eTgLi6pXeTHcL8rvVdp2MEV0AtDoYw2NJ/j10cJMmF6oseSbsMlR8LWngRccQ0Hlg1cu8zASAc/p4zGgfD9dPNGvpGvAIvPaB2Wf@wT/m/aj2fjuzxR8fIoFUa/9BzG@@htQvgHIkUJMz2kZab0JPn5/Bc)):

```
import tracemalloc as tm
from random import random
import gc

n = 10**5

def start(label):
  global x, label_
  label_ = label
  gc.collect()
  tm.start()
  x = {random(): random() for _ in range(n)}

def stop():
  global x
  print(f'{tm.get_traced_memory()[1]:10,}', label_)
  tm.stop()
  if label_ != 'baseline':
    assert len(x) == n
    assert list(x.values()) == sorted(x.values()), list(x.values())
  del x
  gc.collect()

for _ in range(2):

  start('baseline')
  stop()

  start('original')
  x = dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
  stop()

  start('better 1')
  x = list(x.items())
  x.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
  x = dict(x)
  stop()

  start('better 2')
  ks = list(x)
  ks.sort(key=x.get)
  x = dict(zip(ks, map(x.pop, ks)))
  stop()

  start('sort keys, sort vals')
  keys = list(x)
  keys.sort(key=x.get)
  vals = list(x.values())
  del x
  vals.sort()
  x = dict(zip(keys, vals))
  stop()

  start('sort keys, sort vals 2')
  keys = list(x)
  keys.sort(key=x.get, reverse=True)
  vals = list(x.values())
  del x
  vals.sort(reverse=True)
  x = {}
  while keys:
    x[keys.pop()] = vals.pop()
  stop()

  print()
```

Comment: Wouldnt `keys = list(x)` basicly double the size of the dictionary? Does it not create a duplicate?

Comment: No, why would it? It doesn't duplicate any of the key objects (it just stores another 8 bytes reference to each) and has nothing to do with the dict's own data and the value objects. For your 10^8 keys, that's thus only 0.8 GB.

Comment: Quite cool, didn't know if tio.run. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be using a dict for this use case, given that although dicts in modern Python maintain their order they aren't really built to be sorted.

In fact, if you don't have enough memory to make a single extra copy of this data (even just the references to it), you probably don't even want it all in memory in any form.  Consider moving this data into a database that'll support whatever operations the rest of your program needs without having to load all the data into memory.

That said, if you *need* to sort a dictionary but without consuming space in proportion to the size of the dictionary, popping items out and re-adding them in order (i.e. selection sort) seems like the way to do it; more efficient sorting algorithms generally depend on the ability to arbitrarily swap or re-order items (which you can't do with a dict) or make temporary copies of subsets of the data (which we're assuming we can't do under our space constraints).  Unfortunately selection sort has O(N^2) time complexity, but it does have the desired O(1) space complexity.

```
def inplace_dict_sort(d: dict) -> None:
    def swap(i):
        return i[1], i[0]
    k, v = min(d.items(), key=swap)
    while True:
        d[k] = d.pop(k)
        try:
            k, v = min((i for i in d.items() if swap(i) > (v, k)), key=swap)
        except ValueError:
            return

d = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'foo', 'd': 'qux', 'e': 'ola'}
inplace_dict_sort(d)
print(d)
# {'b': 'bar', 'a': 'foo', 'c': 'foo', 'e': 'ola', 'd': 'qux'}
```

Comment: It's not O(1) space. I think because popping doesn't "free" slots, only marks them as deleted.

Comment: For example with 1000 items you [double its size](https://tio.run/##dVDLasMwELz7K/a4Atc45FICya3XnkovwQhjrZvFtiTWclLn510pAYe@9iDQaDQzO34OJ2e3z16WxVALbH1fN6QNN0GPTgKaHaSLgqcDvDpLuwziJO54qT2yugNphMIkFvi4qfJ4ltXtpcvhDHsY2KIpONAwosqho3mfBNSNczlxT/AmEz3UzLGr4j9TeOexUyseZH6QfhggQ@sEOO4BqxnwmhUOgOdorn4lSEOfDfkA73U/0YuIk@8@9/WyzKRUsZKiFTdElRGlth@Em7Islcq8sI21FVqPfCXXao0R/aPYf6jL8gU) from 37 kB to 74 kB.

Comment: [More tests](https://tio.run/##bZHBasMwDIbvfQrdYoMXnI3BKCS3XXcau5QSQqysIoltFLdd9/KZnUJKt@lgsPxL3y/ZX8LB2acXz/NssAOyfmharA21oZ4cB2G2kC4SHip4cxa3G4iRtNO58YLkNZGCMRzZAu2KvYqn3i8vvYITlDCSFSangOMkpIIeL2VqIBfN@UADwjsf8dbN7Pp9rDO5d170cs0HvtxEvwCCoHMMFOeAFQa0eoUKxCnC5R8HKfCrRR/goxmO@Mrs@J5zHW@zSQSbCNzYTxTPWit41LpQUGi9rMMk33FpecdujJxJXKVWJphnskFYBdk2U9FmXU/0ja6r67QYtKbMoKwgS9p//uPW4r5UzvMP) from 500 to 2000 items, you always double its size.

Comment: [683 items](https://tio.run/##bZHBaoQwEIbvPsXcTMBKl4LIgt567an0skgQM3aDmoQx7ta@vE0UlG07h0Am/8z3z8TO7mr0S25pWSS2oLTt6waFVI0ToyHH5BnChcNTCW9G4zkCH0E73mvLFN8SIQjdRBrU5VQl/nyu1pcugRsUMCjNZKocDiPjCXQ4F6EBXzX3q@oR3mnCo5u8dJWvk6k1lnV8zzuaD9EvAFPQGgLl54AdBmr3CiWwm4fzPw5C4FeD1sFH3U/4SmTokbONF0WBoAOBav2JLMtPCWR5ti5CBsd@XWlLZvCEkW0izQPGktKO6QTic5x4g0KM6htNK0RYCWpZxFCUEAftPz9xtHgs5cvyAw) is a border case where you don't double, for 682 and 684 you do.