# Deleting/rearranging/adding in very large tsv files Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a very large tsv file (1.2GB, 5 columns, 38m lines). I want to delete a column, add a column of ID's (1 to 38m), and rearrange the column order. How can I do this without using a ridiculous amount of memory?

Language of choice is Python, though open to other solutions.

Comment: Is it the order of the rows or the columns you wish to rearrange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read, manipulate, and write one row at a time. Not loading the entire file to memory, this will have a very low memory signature.

```
import csv
with open(fileinpath, 'rb') as fin, open(fileoutpath, 'wb') as fout:
    freader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = '\t')
    fwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = '\t')
    idx = 1
    for line in freader:
        line[4], line[0] = line[0], line[4] #switches position between first and last column
        del line[3] #delete fourth column
        line.insert(0, idx)
        fwriter.writerow(line)
        idx += 1
```

(This is written in python2.7, and deletes the fourth column for an example)

Regarding rearranging the order - I assume it's the order of columns - this could be done in the manipulation part. There's an example of switching the order of the first and last column.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `awk` to do this, i will not say 1.2GB will take huge amount of memory.

if you want to delete c3

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2,$4,$5,NR}' input.txt > output.txt
```

the raw output is 
c1    c2    c4    c5    columnId(1 to 38m)

$1 is coloumn1, $2 is column2, and so on. NR is the number of line.

if you want to rearrange, just change the order of $1,$2,$4,$5 and NR,

Comment: Should there be a "\t" instead of ","?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends enormously on how much context is needed need to rewrite the lines and to determine the new ordering.

**If** it's possible to rewrite the individual lines without regard to context (depends on how the ID number is derived), then you can use the `csv` module to read the file line-by-line as @Tal Kremerman illustrates, and write it out line-by-line in the same order. If you can determine the correct ordering of the lines at this time, then you can add an extra field indicating the new order they should appear in.

<s>Then you can do a second pass to sort/rearrange the lines into the correct order. There are many recent threads on "how to sort huge files with Python", e.g. [How to sort huge files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665925/how-to-sort-huge-files-with-python)</s> **I think Tal Kremerman is right that the OP only wants to rearrange columns, and not rows**

Comment: Hmmm. I read this as if he wants to rearrange the columns, not the rows.

Comment: If that's the case, then your solution covers everything :). I guess the OP needs to be more explicit here.